# How to serve relative source urls outside root from NGINX

Tags: nginx

This seems very basic, but I am not able to solve this.
I want NGINX to serve source urls outside the current root, basically starting with `../`

This is my directory

```
common
root (NGINX root)
    ->index.html (NGINX default index)
    common (another common folder)
```

I want to be able to serve

```
src="../common/whatever" /*outer common folder*/
src="./common" /*inner common folder; Cannot change unfortunately*/
```

As you can see, simple `location /common` will not work.

This is my current NGINX conf,

```
server
{

  listen 83 default_server;
  listen [::]:83 default_server ipv6only=on;

  root C:/www/root;
  index index.html index.htm;

  #This does not work for inner /common folder
  location /common {
    root C:/www;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do the reverse:

```
root/
  common/*
  site/
  site/common/*
```

and do something like

```
 location /common {
   try_files site/$uri $uri ...;
 }
```

etc... which gives you `$root/site/common/FILE, $root/common/FILE...`.